# Cannot add any stylesheets to module in prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've encountered problem with adding any stylesheets to prestashop front office. I was reading multiple articles, tried multiple solutions and I can't get it to work. Adding styles to back office was not a problem (but that this code for adding styles to back office is workaround I think). Here is the module code. (I've added stylesheet import in multiple places to check every solution. In other modules this methods works as intended). Sorry for messy code I'm not that good in PHP.

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit();

class PromotionBanner extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'promotionbanner';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'example';
        $this->author_uri = 'https://example.com';
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7.1.0', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->dir = '/modules/promotionbanner';
        $this->css_path = Tools::getShopDomainSsl(true, true) . __PS_BASE_URI__ . 'modules/' . $this->name
            . '/' . $this->_path . 'views/css/';

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Promotion Banner', 'promotionbanner');
        $this->description = $this->l('This module provides configurable promotion banner on your website');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall the module?', 'promotionbanner');
    }

    private function updateConf()
    {
        Configuration::updateValue('banner_text', $this->l('Wybrane produkty tańsze o 15%! Kod rabatowy: '));
        Configuration::updateValue('banner_coupon_code', $this->l('Wybierz kupon rabatowy'));
    }

    public function install()
    {
        $this->updateConf();
        return parent::install() && $this -> registerHook('displayWrapperTop') && $this->registerHook('header');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall() || !Configuration::deleteByName('promotionbanner_module') &&
            !Configuration::deleteByName('banner_coupon_code'))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function hookDisplayWrapperTop($params)
    {
        $this->context->smarty->assign(
            array(
                'banner_text' => Configuration::get('banner_text'),
                'banner_coupon_code' => Configuration::get('banner_coupon_code')
            )
        );

        $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet(
            'modules-promotion-banner2', //This id has to be unique
            'modules/'.$this->name.'/views/css/front.css',
            array('media' => 'all', 'priority' => 150)
        );

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'promotionbanner.tpl');
    }

    public function hookHeader() {
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path . 'views/css/front.css', 'all');
        $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet(
            'modules-promotion-banner', //This id has to be unique
            'modules/'.$this->name.'/views/css/front.css',
            array('media' => 'all', 'priority' => 150)
        );
    }

    public function hookActionFrontControllerSetMedia($params) {
        $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet(
            'module-promotionbanner-style',
            'modules/'.$this->name.'/views/css/front.css',
            [
                'media' => 'all',
                'priority' => 200,
            ]
        );
    }

    public function getPromotions()
    {
        $cart_rule = _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_rule';
        $request = "SELECT $cart_rule.id_cart_rule, " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "cart_rule_lang.name, $cart_rule.code " .
            "FROM $cart_rule INNER JOIN " . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_rule_lang ON ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_rule.id_cart_rule='
            . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_rule_lang.id_cart_rule WHERE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_rule.code IS NOT NULL';
        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $cupons = $db->executeS($request);
        $parsedCupons = array();
        foreach ($cupons as $cupon) {
            array_push($parsedCupons, array(
                'code' => $cupon['code'],
                'name' => $cupon['name']
            ));
        }
        return $parsedCupons;
    }

    public function displayForm()
    {
        $form = $this->renderForm();

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'banner_text' => Configuration::get('banner_text'),
            'banner_coupon_code' => Configuration::get('banner_coupon_code'),
            'form_url' => AdminController::$currentIndex . '&configure=' . $this->name . '&token=' . Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
            'name' => $this->name,
            'form_tpl' => $form,
            'coupon_codes' => $this->getPromotions()
        ));
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(array(
            $this->css_path . 'fontawesome-all.min.css',
            $this->css_path . 'module.css'
        ));

        $this->output = $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path . 'views/templates/admin/menu.tpl');

        return $this->output;
    }

    public function renderForm()
    {
        $helper = new HelperForm();

        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex . '&configure=' . $this->name;
        $helper->title = $this->displayName;
        $helper->show_toolbar = false;
        $helper->toolbar_scroll = false;
        $helper->submit_action = 'submit' . $this->name;
        $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
            'save' =>
                array(
                    'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
                    'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex . '&configure=' . $this->name . '&save' . $this->name .
                        '&token=' . Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                )
        );

        $helper->fields_value = array(
            'banner_text' => Configuration::get('banner_text'),
            'banner_coupon_code' => Configuration::get('banner_coupon_code')
        );

        return $helper->generateForm(array($this->getConfigForm()));
    }

    public function getConfigForm()
    {
        $fields_form = array(
            'form' => array(
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Banner text before code: '),
                        'name' => 'banner_text',
                        'lang' => false,
                        'required' => true,
                        'size' => 20
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'label' => $this->l('Coupon code: '),
                        'name' => 'banner_coupon_code',
                        'required' => true,
                        'options' => array(
                            'query' => $this->getPromotions(),
                            'id' => 'code',
                            'name' => 'name'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
                )
            )
        );

        return $fields_form;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        $output = "";

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit' . $this->name)) {
            $banner_text = strval(Tools::getValue('banner_text'));
            $banner_coupon_code = strval(Tools::getValue('banner_coupon_code'));

            if (!isset($banner_text) || !isset($banner_coupon_code))
                $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Please insert something in this field.'));
            else {
                Configuration::updateValue('banner_text', $banner_text);
                Configuration::updateValue('banner_coupon_code', $banner_coupon_code);
                $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Field updated successfully!'));
            }
        }
        return $output . $this->displayForm();
    }


}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.

1. Double-check if your file path is correct.
2. Don't forget to clean your cache. Disable it at all while coding. I had a great struggle with it while I was coding my module. Even after disabling it I still sometimes needed to clear the cache (no idea why).
3. Try to change priority parameter for example to 10. Remove the "media" parameter at all. Add the "server" parameter and set its value to the "local". Like this: array('priority' => 10, 'server' => 'local');

Comment: Did you check if the hook is working correctly, and if you don't have a other module installed that might have a interfering override?

Comment: Okay so this is everything that I've tried. I double checked my paths even doing echo of it on screen. I tried to register the stylesheet on the different ID. I've removed the "media" parameter from the configuration array. I disabled cache in chrome and I'm clearing the prestashop cache on every try! Still no success. I was looking on other modules how they're doing it. The ageverification module that is installed on my local prestashop is registering hook "header" and have a function to this registered header. And the official ps_imageslider module has "displayHeader" hook registered!

Comment: Also the official documentation is mentioning **hookActionFrontControllerSetMedia** which I tried and it also doesn't work. So I'm kinda defeated by now. Every module maker have a different approach to this and documentation is messy and not complete. And I forgot to mention about my prestashop version: **1.7.6.1**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so I've managed to successfully register the stylesheet in the prestashop **1.7.6.1**. But I think this is a good time to mention some of my mistakes and address some of the problems.

**Checklist of registering a stylesheet in front office**

1. Use correct hook for the job.
   *My problem has been unsolved because I've used a wrong hook.*
2. Make sure that your `__construct()` registered a **official hook for registering stylesheets (prestashop 1.7.x)**. The correct hook is: `$this->registerHook('actionFrontControllerSetMedia');` you can find official docs here (If you don't have front controller in your module): https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/getting-started/asset-management/#without-a-front-controller-module
3. Make sure that you registered your hook function with `$params` (I don't know why but it doesn't work without a function parameter defined... This also stopped me from successfull register). The proper function should look like this:

```
        $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet(
            'stylesheet-id', //This id has to be unique
            'modules/'.$this->name.'/views/css/front.css',
            array('server' => 'local', 'priority' => 10)
        );
    }
```

4. As @bakis mentioned. After every try **clear your browser cache + prestashop cache** for chrome or chromium users I would suggest to disable the browser cache in inspector window completely.
5. I know that `$this->context->controller->addCSS` still exists, but this function is useful only for back office stylesheet register. Even the official docs are saying about it

> Backward compatibility is kept for the addJS(), addCSS(), addJqueryUI() and addJqueryPlugin() methods.

That's pretty much everything about this question. I hope it will help someone in the future who is searching for answer.

Comment: It worked only if i placed css file **not** in `views` directory. I've put it in `css` directory placed directly in module root